# How to ask permission from a stranger to take their portrait?

Tags: tips, street-photography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Street Photography - Hints on approaching people](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/610/street-photography-hints-on-approaching-people)

I tend to see lot of possible subjects everywhere (streets, bus stations, garages, tech events...). Personally, I am a little wary to ask people if I can take their picture because they don't expect it and creates a bit of embarrassment for them. What's the best way to ask people for permission to take their picture?